# Error when adding c++ code to Swift Xcode project

Tags: c++, swift, xcode

The bridging header file:

```
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import "sdi_omr/src/SDIOMR.hpp"
```

SDIOMR.hpp file (set as **Default c++ header**):
Note:The SDIOMR.cpp file also exist and is set to **Default c++ source**

```
#ifndef SDIOMR_H
#define SDIOMR_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector> 
#include <map>
#include "ImagePreprocessor.hpp"
#include "INIReader.hpp"
#endif

class SDIOMR{
    private:
        bool isProcessable = false;
        cv::Mat fixedFrame;
        cv::Mat inputFrame;
        ImagePreprocessor imagePreprocessor;
        std::vector<cv::Mat> segments;
        INIReader reader;
    public:
        bool isReadable(cv::Mat frame);
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> readForm();
        // SDIOMR();
        SDIOMR(INIReader inireader);
};

#endif // SDIOMR_H
```

And I'm getting this error:

[image]

Need help to fix this problem.

Comment: C++ classes should be inside #ifdef __cplusplus ... #endif. Add them in bridging header

Comment: @Cy-4AH yes, the error is gone when I put the include inside #ifdef __cplusplus ... #endif but then I cannot access the isReadable prop in my swift code. If there is a way I'd like to know.

Comment: What version of Swift (and Xcode) are you using? Swift - C++ interop is only available since Swift 5.9, which comes with Xcode 15.

Comment: Swift 5.9 Xcode 15.0.1

Comment: Now it's question about Swift/C++ interoperability